# Xamarin POST method not returning correct value

Tags: c#, xamarin, request

I am having a problem with sending a POST request and getting a response. I have made local PHP script which returns some string values, and I can't get it to work with Xamarin.

This is the method I am using for to send the request:

```cs
public async Task<string> Post_Request()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/server.php");
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        return "BAD!";
    }
}
```

When debbuging, the program does not go into the if or else code branches on the  "if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)" condition.

This is my PHP script:

```xml
<?php
return 
"
{
"user":"01",
"name":"ime"
}
"
//echo "OK";
?>
```

Comment: `localhost` is referring to the device|emulator itself so unless you are trying to connect to a web server that is running on the device|emulator that will not work. Use the public|same subnet IP address that your PHP server|PC is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample post request that I have used.

```
var objRequest = new CustomerDetailsRequest() {
    customerId = 1
};

string url = $"/api/v1/CustomerDetails";
var requestBody = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objRequest));
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    CustomerDetailsResponse data = new CustomerDetailsResponse();
    try
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3000");
        var content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
        var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDetailsResponse>(response);

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode && result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return data;
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this is confusing